# ios 7.1 UITextField tint color doesn't change in storyboard

Tags: ios, uitextfield, tintcolor

Up till iOS 7.0, the text field tint color changed to the color you set in storyboard.
As of iOS 7.1, it won't change unless you do it programmatically.

Is this a bug? Does anyone know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution to work with storyboard.

1) Go to "Identity Inspector"

2) Add "tintColor" attribute in "User Defined Runtime Attributes"

3) Set the desired color.

Thats it.

[image]

Or if you want to use same tint color for all textfields throughout the app, juse use,

[[UITextField appearance] setTintColor:color];

Answer (score 3):

I have also faced this problem but tint color is working from code.

```
self.txtPassword.tintColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
```