# Image asset catalog color not changing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimage

I added one image set and set its Render As -> Template Image.

Added one button to storyboard and changed its tint color. It works perfectly when I check in the simulator.

Issue - 1) But color don't get updated in the storyboard.

I have added one image view and changed its tint color from the storyboard.

Issue - 2) But color don't get updated in the storyboard nor the color change appears in the simulator.

I have added one image view programmatically and set its image and tint color that works perfectly in the simulator.

What might be the above issues any idea?

Comment: So it works completely fine doing it programmatically, but fails when setting it up via storyboard?

Comment: @Firo Yes it works

Comment: I think this will help:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/30741478/4637057

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue 1) That seems issue with Xcode, next releases may come up with fix.

Issue 2) That seems issue with Xcode too.. When I faced that situation I had to add ImageView programmatically which worked. You may also try IBDesignable or Custom class or Extension which changes renderMode property.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue - 1) But color don't get updated in the storyboard.**
  have look this one :
[ios 7.1 UITextField tint color doesn't change in storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23268090/ios-7-1-uitextfield-tint-color-doesnt-change-in-storyboard)

**Issue - 2) But color don't get updated in the storyboard nor the color change  appears in the simulator.**

this issue arise for the template rendering mode with a UIImageView in a storyboard or xib, on iOS 7 , iOS 8 , iOS9 and iOS10 cause it is still buggy.

more information check this thread [Modify UIImage renderingMode from storyboard/xib file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19517334/modify-uiimage-renderingmode-from-storyboard-xib-file)

I think so programmatically is good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Was it suppose to reflect **Template Image** color on StoryBoard by changing **Tint** ?

I checked on **Xcode 8.2.1**, **Xcode 8.1**, **Xcode 8.0** and **Xcode 7.3.1**

**None** of them reflected the color on StoryBoard. Its works fine on Simulator and iPhone though.

I don't think this functionality was ever there. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've been able to get it to work is by creating an outlet of the UIImageView and calling this in viewDidLoad (or in VC):

```
imageView.tintColorDidChange()
```

This has been a bug since iOS 7 or 8 I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue is resolved in Xcode 11. 
I tested on iOS 13, 12 and 11 and it works fine now in storyboard, simulator and device 
So I replaced my code by setting image in XCAsset as Template and changing tintColor of UIImageView and UIButton in storyboards and Xibs.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, from Xcode, go to **assets** > then select your image > then from Inspectors menu (on the right): change the value of **Render as** to **Template image**

[image]

Then go to your storyboard > then change **Tint** color as you wish, and voila!

Answer (score 0):

**Try**

Clear the derived data

Clean Project

**or**

Use custom button

Comment: With button its working and i don't think cleaning project and derived data will help. Yet I tried its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Please take iboutlet of that imageview and change the tint color programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing all views, maybe it helps:

[image: screenshot]